Is it possible to update the RITM variables via a REST call to the sc_req_item table?
I need to update a variable on an RITM (Requested Item) using the inbound REST API.
I understand that variable values are stored in the sc_item_option table, which is linked to the sc_req_item table through the sc_item_option_mtom table.
I've been informed that it's possible to update variables by making a PUT request to the sc_req_item table, including the variable and its value in the request body. However, I haven't been successful with this approach.
Am I correct in thinking that this method won't work, and that updating a variable value would actually require a PUT request to the sc_item_option table instead?
please help how to achieve this.enter image description here

Have you tried the usual approach of using variables.some_var_name as a key for your payload?

hm, I tried variables.some_var_name, doesn't seem to work.

I followed these steps: First, I retrieved the "sys_id" of the custom field using the endpoint:
{{BaseUrl}}/api/now/table/sc_item_option_mtom?sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=True&sysparm_query=request_item%3D&sysparm_fields=sc_item_option.
Then, using the retrieved "sys_id", I made a "PATCH" request to update the custom field value. The request was successful, and when I checked in Postman, the field displayed the updated value. However, when I checked within the system, the "value" was not populated as expected. Attached a screenshot in the question
